# Binary Search Tree In-order traversal without recursion or additional data structures

Tags: algorithm, traversal

If nodes in a Binary Search Tree had pointers back to its parent node, is it possible to do an In-order traversal without the need for recursion or additional data structures?

Comment: This question is not a proper fit for Stack Overflow, so let me answer it before they close it. The answer is: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Can you show me please?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually if there is a pointer to the parent node or not. There should be several examples here non how to do this.

Comment: Without a parent pointer you probably have to build some additional structure. Doesn't matter if you call it a stack or something else. With parent pointer you just have to decide what to do and where to go next based on the information where you came from. If you came from parent go left. If you came from left child print parent and go right. If you came from right child go to parent. If parent is null we're done.

Comment: Thanks Dialecticus. I thought the same but I am struggling to build a working algorithm. If you know the implementation and you can share it that would be great. thanks

Comment: Google Morris Traversal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a fit for SO. It's interesting though... hint: imagine visiting cities using an in-order traversal. Keep your memories with you as stickers on a suitcase. Only put the sticker on for a city at the correct moment.

Comment: Can we use a queue? Or no data structures are allowed?

Comment: No data structure allowed. Just making use of the child node pointing to the parent node

Comment: Ah, so you confirm that it is a tree that has pointers from the child to the parent node. It would be good if at least you could edit your question and add the structure of a node.

Comment: @trincot I have changed "reference" to "pointers"

Comment: What is the preferred language for an answer?

Comment: Any chance your node values have a fixed range?

Comment: @trincot - C# would be great

Comment: @Maruthi Adithya - the tree can grow and shrink at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of the previous node during the traversal, which will help decide which way to go next.

In C#:

```cs
class Node {
    /* ... */
    public void inorder() {
        Node curr = this;
        Node prev = null;
        Node next = null;
        while (curr != null) {
            if (curr.right != null && prev == curr.right) {
                next = curr.parent;
            } else if (curr.left == null || prev == curr.left) {
                Console.WriteLine(curr.data);  // <-- visit the node.
                next = curr.right != null ? curr.right : curr.parent;
            } else {
                next = curr.left;
            }
            prev = curr;
            curr = next;
        }
    }
};
```

In C++ it could look like this:

```cpp
void inorder(Node* root) {
    Node * curr = root;
    Node * prev = NULL;
    Node * next = NULL;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        if (curr->right != NULL && prev == curr->right) {
            next = curr->parent;
        } else if (curr->left == NULL || prev == curr->left) {
            cout << curr->data << " ";  // <-- visit the node.
            next = curr->right != NULL ? curr->right : curr->parent;
        } else {
            next = curr->left;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first node, you just start at the root and go left as far as possible.

To get from any node to the next:

- If the node has a right child, then go right, and then go left as far as possible.
- Otherwise, follow parent pointers up until you get to an ancestor on the right (i.e., you get there from a left child)

You're done when you go up from the root.

Comment: thanks Matt. Would you have a coded example for me to see?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example.

```
Map<TreeNode,TreeNode> parent; // available 

Set<TreeNode> set = new HashSet<>(); // maintain visited nodes

TreeNode curr = root;

while(curr!=null){

  if(!set.contains(curr.left) && curr.left!=null){
     curr = curr.left;
  }else if(!set.contains(curr.right) && curr.right!=null){
     System.out.print(curr.value+" ");
     curr = curr.right;
  }else{
     if(curr.right==null){
        System.out.print(curr.value+" ");
     }
     set.add(curr); // mark it as completely visited
     curr = parent.get(curr);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good start, now please eliminate the need for `Map<>` and `Set<>` :)